# Why is my video fast forwarded after converting it from a DVD with VLC and how can I fix it?

Tags: vlc, dvd

I am trying to convert some series I have on DVD to a digital video file like MP4.

However the first few seconds *after* the MGM intro are sped forward. In fact, only the video is sped up. The audio is just fine. That leads to the video and audio being out of sync for the rest of the episode.

I have converted many episodes of the same series without problems before using H-264 and MPEG-4 AAC.

Other codecs do not work either. I have tried MPEG-1 through 4, DIVX 1 through 3, H-263 through 265, and WMV 1 & 2. The problem persists.

Using other containers such as MKV, Webm and WMV did not work either.

---

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 having a Ryzen 9 3900 XT and a RX 5600 XT card.

What can I do to solve this problem and have the video be converted properly?

Comment: I would try Handbrake instead.

Comment: @ChanganAuto That works awfully well. Thank you!